# What should go in [Name]View.xaml.cs files?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am creating a desktop application using WPF & Caliburn MVVM. In my "Views" directory, I have several files that follow this pattern:

ExampleView.xaml <= this is the actual UI design...

ExampleView.xaml.cs <= what goes here?

Then I also have a ViewModel for each view.

Can somebody explain what should go in the ExampleViewModel.cs and what should go in the ExampleView.xaml.cs? It looks like my ViewModels inherit from "Screen", where my ExampleView.xaml.cs inherits from "Window".

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That is your "Codebehind" for the view.  Many people use the codebehind to interact with their view.  However, many people prefer a decoupled approach called MVVM that uses a viewmodel instead.  The MVVM architecture is more unit-testing friendly and easier for code reuse.

So in summary, the ExampleView.xaml.cs is used to interact with your controls on the view.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your views can be inherited from `Window` or `UserControl` or other WPF classes. In MVVM the view is the user interface and the view model is an abstraction of the view exposing public properties and commands. Instead of the controller of the MVC pattern, or the presenter of the MVP pattern, MVVM has a binder. In the view model, the binder mediates communication between the view and the data binder.

But your view can contains UI-logic that is not depend on data from ViewModel. This logic can be added to [Name]View.xaml.cs files as View's (and inner control's) event handlers, for example `OnLoad`, `OnResize`. It calls [Code behind](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa970568(v=vs.100).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a couple WPF apps using MVVMLight Nuget and all of my [views].aspx.cs only have the auto-generated code.  I didn't need to put anything in the views code behind because it goes in my view model.  I also converted some web apps and a couple windows 8 store apps to MVVM and almost completely eliminated all code from the views code behind.

The only time I have put something in the views code behind is maybe to instantiate a view model to go along with that view in very isolated situations.

There is much debate out there whether to have zero code to follow MVVM best or having some code in the code behind is okay.  Personal preference and based on work load, complexity, timelines, etc.